# Splitting a Java String return empty array?

Tags: java, split

I have a String something like this

```
"myValue"."Folder"."FolderCentury";
```

I want to split from dot("."). I was trying with the below code:

```
String a = column.replace("\"", "");
String columnArray[] = a.split(".");
```

But `columnArray` is coming empty. What I am doing wrong here?

I will want to add one more thing here someone its possible String array object will contain spitted value like mentioned below only two object rather than three.?

```
columnArray[0]= "myValue"."Folder";
columnArray[1]= "FolderCentury";
```

Comment: I have added some more specification in question so it should not be look like duplicate.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Note that [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a **regex**.

You need to escape the [special char](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) `.` (That means "any character"):

```
 String columnArray[] = a.split("\\.");
```

(Escaping a regex is done by `\`, but in Java, `\` is written as `\\`).

You can also use [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns a **literal pattern String** for the specified String.

`String columnArray[] = a.split(Pattern.quote("."));`

By *escaping* the regex, you tell the compiler to treat the `.` as the **string** `.` and not the *special char* `.`.

Comment: i have added one more thing in same question is this possible?

Comment: `columnArray[0]= "myValue"."Folder";` This won't compile.

Comment: Yes but String is inside columnArray[0] and it would worked i have some more complexity how these value coming only i want how i can split it like two string

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have asked here see if this can exaplin you my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508782/split-a-string-in-java-against-the-split-rule

Answer (score 3):

You must escape the dot.

```
String columnArray[] = a.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 2):

split() accepts an regular expression. So you need to skip '.' to not consider it as a regex meta character.

```
String[] columnArray = a.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 1):

While using special characters need to use the particular escape sequence with it.

'.' is a special character so need to use escape sequence before '.' like:

```
 String columnArray[] = a.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 1):

The next code:

```
   String input = "myValue.Folder.FolderCentury";
   String regex = "(?!(.+\\.))\\.";
   String[] result=input.split(regex);
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Produces the required output:

```
[myValue.Folder, FolderCentury]
```

The regular Expression tweaks a little with negative look-ahead (this `(?!)` part), so it will only match the last dot on a String with more than one dot.